# calculating highest frequency of recorded voice in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, fft

I want to record user's voice and conduct FFT on it so that I can get some frequency values and calculate the highest tone of that recording. Has anybody done anything related to it in BlackBerry. It would be great if I can get some help regarding this

Comment: The highest pitch or the highest frequency?  Even low male voices will show up in an FFT with some really high frequency components, near Fs/2, especially for sibilants.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/blackberry-real-time-audio/) for real time FFT computation. You should be able to modify the code to work for you.